# How to server-side rendering Angular app with Apache server?

Tags: angular, apache, server-side

We've built an Angular v>4 app served by an Apache Server.
I know it exists Angular Universal for Node server to allow server side rendering. Does it exist any equivalent for Apache Server ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal always use node.js for dynamic build server-side page.
You can build prerender by universal and host static with Apache or run `node server.js` and proxy request from Apache to node server(port)

Comment: i believe the question was if Apache can be used without involving Node

Comment: @AkberIqbal without node - only with use prerender ( like https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/prerender.ts )